# Methods didn't run when used TestNG annotation

Tags: selenium

//  When running below, @Test and @After method code didn't run.Using Selenium-jave-2.54.jar and TestNG

//Creating Admin

```
public class createAdmin1 {

    public String url = "http://10.120.6.12:8080/#/login";
    public WebDriver driver;
    //@SuppressWarnings("unused")
```

//Open Browser

```
@BeforeMethod
      public void Login() {

          WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
         // driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
          driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.navigate().to(url);


      }
```

// Login to server and create Admin

```
@Test
  public void CreateAdmin() {

        /*driver.get(url);
        driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("at.pretendcompany@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("abc123");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/button")).click();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        */
        //driver.get(url);
        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        //driver.navigate().to(url);
        driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("test");
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("test123");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/button")).click();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      driver.findElement(By.id("snAdmins")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/button[3]")).click();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.findElement(By.id("adminId")).sendKeys("user1@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("user1");
        driver.findElement(By.id("pwConfirmInput")).sendKeys("user1");

        driver.findElement(By.id("adminQuestion")).sendKeys("Who are you?");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.id("adminAnswer")).sendKeys("I am admin");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Save')]")).isDisplayed());
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Save')]")).click();

  }
  // Close the browser after create admin finished.

  @AfterMethod
  public void Quit() {


    driver.close();
        System.out.println("Driver closed");
  }

}
```

/*// Error Getting while running it using TestNG

```
    [TestNG] Running:
      C:\Users\sperla\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse-237279322\testng-customsuite.xml

    [Utils] Attempting to create E:\AutomationDevelopment\ExtremeCloud-POC\ExOL_Login_TestNG\test-output\Default suite\Default test.html
    [Utils]   Directory E:\AutomationDevelopment\ExtremeCloud-POC\ExOL_Login_TestNG\test-output\Default suite exists: true
    [Utils] Attempting to create E:\AutomationDevelopment\ExtremeCloud-POC\ExOL_Login_TestNG\test-output\Default suite\Default test.xml
    [Utils]   Directory E:\AutomationDevelopment\ExtremeCloud-POC\ExOL_Login_TestNG\test-output\Default suite exists: true
    FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod Quit
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Login.createAdmin1.Quit(createAdmin1.java:105)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:515)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:216)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:712)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:823)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1131)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:778)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1225)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1150)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1075)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1047)
        at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:75)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:46)

    FAILED: CreateAdmin
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Login.createAdmin1.CreateAdmin(createAdmin1.java:71)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:646)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:823)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1131)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:778)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1225)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1150)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1075)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1047)
        at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:75)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:46)


    ===============================================
        Default test
        Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
        Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
    ===============================================


    ===============================================
    Default suite
    Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
    Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
    ===============================================

    [Utils] Attempting to create E:\AutomationDevelopment\ExtremeCloud-POC\ExOL_Login_TestNG\test-output\junitreports\TEST-Login.createAdmin1.xml
    [Utils]   Directory E:\AutomationDevelopment\ExtremeCloud-POC\ExOL_Login_TestNG\test-output\junitreports exists: true
    [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@27f674d: 11 ms
    [Utils] Attempting to create E:\AutomationDevelopment\ExtremeCloud-POC\ExOL_Login_TestNG\test-output\testng-failed.xml
    [Utils]   Directory E:\AutomationDevelopment\ExtremeCloud-POC\ExOL_Login_TestNG\test-output exists: true
    [Utils] Attempting to create E:\AutomationDevelopment\ExtremeCloud-POC\ExOL_Login_TestNG\test-output\Default suite\testng-failed.xml
    [Utils]   Directory E:\AutomationDevelopment\ExtremeCloud-POC\ExOL_Login_TestNG\test-output\Default suite exists: true
    [TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 11 ms
    [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@1cd072a9: 8 ms
    [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@75bd9247: 28 ms
    [Utils] Problem creating output directory E:\AutomationDevelopment\ExtremeCloud-POC\ExOL_Login_TestNG\test-output\old\Default suite
    [Utils] Attempting to create E:\AutomationDevelopment\ExtremeCloud-POC\ExOL_Login_TestNG\test-output\old\Default suite\toc.html
    [Utils]   Directory E:\AutomationDevelopment\ExtremeCloud-POC\ExOL_Login_TestNG\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
    [Utils] Problem creating output directory E:\AutomationDevelopment\ExtremeCloud-POC\ExOL_Login_TestNG\test-output\old\Default suite
    [Utils] Attempting to create E:\AutomationDevelopment\ExtremeCloud-POC\ExOL_Login_TestNG\test-output\old\Default suite\Default test.properties
    [Utils]   Directory E:\AutomationDevelopment\ExtremeCloud-POC\ExOL_Login_TestNG\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
    [Utils] Problem creating output directory E:\AutomationDevelopment\ExtremeCloud-POC\ExOL_Login_TestNG\test-output\old\Default suite
    [Utils] Attempting to create E:\AutomationDevelopment\ExtremeCloud-POC\ExOL_Login_TestNG\test-output\old\Default suite\index.html
    [Utils]   Directory E:\AutomationDevelopment\ExtremeCloud-POC\ExOL_Login_TestNG\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
    [Utils] Problem creating output directory E:\AutomationDevelopment\ExtremeCloud-POC\ExOL_Login_TestNG\test-output\old\Default suite
    [Utils] Attempting to create E:\AutomationDevelopment\ExtremeCloud-POC\ExOL_Login_TestNG\test-output\old\Default suite\main.html
    [Utils]   Directory E:\AutomationDevelopment\ExtremeCloud-POC\ExOL_Login_TestNG\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
    [Utils] Problem creating output directory E:\AutomationDevelopment\ExtremeCloud-POC\ExOL_Login_TestNG\test-output\old\Default suite
    [Utils] Attempting to create E:\AutomationDevelopment\ExtremeCloud-POC\ExOL_Login_TestNG\test-output\old\Default suite\groups.html
    [Utils]   Directory E:\AutomationDevelopment\ExtremeCloud-POC\ExOL_Login_TestNG\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
    [Utils] Problem creating output directory E:\AutomationDevelopment\ExtremeCloud-POC\ExOL_Login_TestNG\test-output\old\Default suite
    [Utils] Problem creating output directory E:\AutomationDevelopment\ExtremeCloud-POC\ExOL_Login_TestNG\test-output\old\Default suite
    [Utils] Problem creating output directory E:\AutomationDevelopment\ExtremeCloud-POC\ExOL_Login_TestNG\test-output\old\Default suite
    [Utils] Attempting to create E:\AutomationDevelopment\ExtremeCloud-POC\ExOL_Login_TestNG\test-output\old\Default suite\classes.html
    [Utils]   Directory E:\AutomationDevelopment\ExtremeCloud-POC\ExOL_Login_TestNG\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
    [Utils] Problem creating output directory E:\AutomationDevelopment\ExtremeCloud-POC\ExOL_Login_TestNG\test-output\old\Default suite
    [Utils] Attempting to create E:\AutomationDevelopment\ExtremeCloud-POC\ExOL_Login_TestNG\test-output\old\Default suite\reporter-output.html
    [Utils]   Directory E:\AutomationDevelopment\ExtremeCloud-POC\ExOL_Login_TestNG\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
    [Utils] Problem creating output directory E:\AutomationDevelopment\ExtremeCloud-POC\ExOL_Login_TestNG\test-output\old\Default suite
    [Utils] Attempting to create E:\AutomationDevelopment\ExtremeCloud-POC\ExOL_Login_TestNG\test-output\old\Default suite\methods-not-run.html
    [Utils]   Directory E:\AutomationDevelopment\ExtremeCloud-POC\ExOL_Login_TestNG\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
    [Utils] Problem creating output directory E:\AutomationDevelopment\ExtremeCloud-POC\ExOL_Login_TestNG\test-output\old\Default suite
    [Utils] Attempting to create E:\AutomationDevelopment\ExtremeCloud-POC\ExOL_Login_TestNG\test-output\old\Default suite\testng.xml.html
    [Utils]   Directory E:\AutomationDevelopment\ExtremeCloud-POC\ExOL_Login_TestNG\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
    [Utils] Attempting to create E:\AutomationDevelopment\ExtremeCloud-POC\ExOL_Login_TestNG\test-output\old\index.html
    [Utils]   Directory E:\AutomationDevelopment\ExtremeCloud-POC\ExOL_Login_TestNG\test-output\old exists: true
    [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@2ff4f00f: 30 ms
    [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@2f7c7260: 3 ms
    [enter image description here][1]


    Please suggest me why is this error though following  testNG annotations correctly.


      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I83dU.png  */
```

Answer (score 0):

In top use

```
      public static WebDriver driver;
```

instead of   public WebDriver driver;

In before method use like below

```
  @BeforeMethod
  public void Login() {

      driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Thank You,
Murali

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have declared a 'public WebDriver driver' in the top of the code. And now what you have to do is don't declare it in the @BeforeMethod again. Now this should work.

@BeforeMethod

public void Login() {

```
     //See here we are just calling the already declared WebDriver.
      driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      driver.navigate().to(url);
      driver.manage().window.maximize();



  }
```